# Prove that $\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}\int_{n}^{\infty} f_{n}(x)dx\neq \int_{n}^{\infty} f(x)dx $

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, pointwise-convergence

> > Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence defined by
> >
> > $$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}1, & \text{if}\;x\geq n,\\0 & \text{if}\;x< n,\end{cases}$$ Prove:
> >
> > 1. $\{f_n\}$ is monotone decreasing and nonnegative.
> > 2. $f_n\to f\equiv 0 \;\;\text{as}\;n\to \infty,$ pointwise.
> > 3. $\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}\int_{n}^{\infty} f_{n}(x)dx\neq \int_{n}^{\infty} f(x)dx.$

Here is my trial:

**Solution**

2. $\exists\,N>x,$ such that $f_n(x)=0,\;\forall \;n\geq N.$ This implies, $f_n\to f\equiv 0, \text{as}\; n\to\infty.$
3. $$\int_{n}^{\infty} f_{n}(x)dx=\int_{n}^{\infty} (1)dx=\infty.$$ So, $$\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}\int_{n}^{\infty} f_{n}(x)dx=\infty.$$ However, $$\int_{n}^{\infty} f(x)dx=0.$$ So, $$\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}\int_{n}^{\infty} f_{n}(x)dx\neq\int_{n}^{\infty} f(x)dx.$$

My question is, how do I show 1.? If I may ask, are my solutions right?

Comment: equation in title: the RHS has an $n$ in it.

Comment: @ Lord Shark the Unknown: Thanks for pointing out the typo! I've corrected it!

Comment: equation in title: the RHS has an $n$ in it.

Comment: Yes, the question is now correct! It does, I mean the integral!

Comment: I believe in the integral appearing after the "However" it is $\int_n^\infty f(x)dx=0$ and not $\int_n^\infty f_n(x)dx=0$.

Comment: How do you calculate a limit of something that is divergent to $\infty$. And how is it that $\int_n^\infty f_n(x) dx = \infty = 0$ at the same time

Comment: equation in title: the RHS has an $n$ in it

Comment: Sorry, Hugocito and Adam! Went for lunch! You are right! It's been corrected

Comment: Why do you keep saying it's been corrected? **The RHS has an $n$ in it**.

Comment: @David C. Ullrich: That's the question statement!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You answer is correct. For 1), just notice that if $n\leq m$ then $f_n(x)=f_m(x)=1$ if $x\geq m$ and $f_n(x)\geq f_m(x)=0$ if $x<m$. Therefore, $f_n\geq f_m$ if $n\leq m$. Draw the graphics to see what is going on.

Comment: Please, you have three if-conditions! Which do I attach to which?

Comment: Your answer for 2 and 3 are correct. I'm proving the 1.

Comment: Clearly $f_n$ is non negative. I'm just justifying $f_n$ is monotone decreasing.

Comment: @ Hugocito: Thanks! I've gotten it!

Comment: You are welcome!